# Bash split large file of 2 line chunks into smaller files

Tags: linux, bash

The file has millions of lines, arranged in 2 line blocks, where 1st line in each block is a header, marked with a `>` , followed by two lines of letter characters.

In linux and/or bash, how to split the file into smaller ones, preserving the 2block structure? Ideally, with some flexibility over how many are output, based on number of output files or the number of blocks per smaller file?

short example:

```
>k99_12
CCTTCTTCAATGCCAATACCCTCGAAGAATTGCACCGCCTCGAACAAACCACATGACACACCCACCGTCACTGGCTGACATTGCCGCACAACTTGAAGCCTATGACCCGCAGGCACTACCTGCCAATGAGGTCTTGAATTTTCTGGATCACTTGGTGACGCCAGTGCACGACTCAGAATCAGTCGACATCTTTGCAGCATTGGGCAGAGTCACTGCGCAA
>k99_27
ATCCAAGCCAGAGAATATGCCTACCCGCATCGCACCGCGATCTCGCAAATGTCGTGTAATCGCGCGGGTATCAACACCCTGAATGCCAATGATTCCTTGCTCAATCAATTCCGCCTCAAGATCATTTTGTGCGCGCCAATTTGATGTCAAAGAGGATGGGTTTCTAACAACAAACCCTGCCACCCAAATCTTTGATGACTCATTATCTAA
>k99_31
CCATTGCGCAAACGGACTGCCGGACACCAAGTGCACCTCGTGCGACAGACCATACTGGTCGTCATAAGAGAGTTCAGGGTTTTCGCGGTGGTCGGCCATGCCGTCCACATTGTGCACCTGCTGGTGCAGCGAACCGCCCATGGCCACATTGATTTCCTGGAAGCCACGGCAAATCCCCAGCAGGGGCACACCCTGCGCGACGCAGGCGCGTACCAAGGGCAAGGTCAGGCTGTCGCGGTGCGGATCCAGCGGCAGACGCGGA
>k99_35
AAAATTGAGTTTGAAGGAATTTCGCATTTCATCAAAAATCAACACGACGAGAGTGGTTCAACAACTATAAAACGTTGGGCAAAGGAATTTATGGACGAAATAAATTGTCCTGTTTGCGAAGGTTCACGATTAAAAAAAGAAGCTTTATTTTTCAAAATTAATGGAAAAAACATCACTGAATTATGCAATATGGATATTTCGGATGTCACGGCTTGGTTTTTGGAATTGAACACCCATTTATCAGATAAACAAAAGACTATAGCGACGGAGGTTATCAAGGAAATAAAAGATCGATTGGCCTTTTTAATGAATGTAGGTTTGGATTATTT
>k99_40
GAGGCCGGCGAAGGCGCGGTGATCGACGAGGAGGACGACGACGCTGGCGCGGGCGAGCGCGTCGGCGAGGGAAACGAGTTCCGCCCTGCCCTGCAGCGCTTTCGGCAAGGCGGTCACGTGCGGCTCGACGGCCAGGACCTTCAGGCCGGCGTCGGCGAGGTGCGCGGCGATCTCGACGGCGGGAGATTCACGGAGGTCGTCGACGTTCGCCTTGAAGGCGAGGCCGAGGCAGGCGACGGCGGCGCCAGAA
>k99_42
AGACCAAATCGCACGGCTAGCAGGATCAAAACGCAAGATGCGCGGGTCTCTTACTTCATCGCGCAGAGTAGGGCGCATCAGCGCGACTTTTTCGCGCACGTCATCGGCGCCTTTGCGGCCGTCTATGTTGAGGTCAAACTCAACCACCACCACCGACACGCCTTCATAACTGCGAGATGTGAGGGCATTGATACCGGCAATGGAATTGACTGCTTCTTCCACTTTTTTAGTCACCTCGCTCTCGACAATTTCAGGAGAGGCGCCTGGATATTCGGTGCTCACGACAACGACGGGCAAATCAATATTAGGAAACTGGTCGATCTTGAGGCGCTGATAAGAGAACAAGCCCAGCACCACAAAGGCAAGCATCACCATCGTTGCGAAGACGGGGTTTTTGAGGCTGACTTTGGTGA
>k99_75
AAAGGTAGCATTGAAGATTATACGCAGTTGTTTCAGGCAGCAGCACAAATTGCGAATGAATCGGCACATATGCAACTCGATATAGATGTCGAGGGATTCAACGAATTTGCTACGGCGGCGGACGACCTCAGTAAGTTATTCACTGGTTTCATTTTGAAGTTGGAGAATGTGAGTATCATCGACGATACTGTATTTTTGACTGCGGTGGCAAATGCTCTCTCGAAGATAAGCAATTTGTCGAAAGTGTTTGGTAAGTTCAAAGAAACTATATTGGGCACTTCGACAATTCGTTTGCCCAAATCCGCACATGATGCATCGGTTATACTGAAAGATGTGGTTGGGCAAATCAATTGTGCAATGACGTATATAAACCATTTTGTCGATTCGAGTGTTCCCGCACCAAGTGTTGCGGAATTATCGAAAGAAGAGAAGAATATAATCGACGCTGCGGTGACAACCATTCACAATTGGAATACATTGTGTGACCAAGGAGTTAGTATTGCCATGTCAAGCGACCCAGATATTCAATTTGTTAGTAATGCGAATCAATCGCT
>k99_76
TCGTAAGCTAACTAAATCAACTGAACAATCTATCACCAATAGTATGTAATCAGAAATCAACTTAAATCTCATATATTAATGAAAGTTTTATCAATTGTTGGAACAAGGCCGGAAATAATTAAGTTATCAAGAGTGTTTCATGAACTTGAAAAATATACTGAACACATTTTAGTACATACAGGTCAAAACTTTGATTATGAACTAAATGAAATATTTTTCAATGATCTTAAAATTAAGAAACCTGATTTTTTTTTAAATGTTGTTGGCGAATCTTTAGCTGATACTATTGCAAACATAATTTCCAAATCCGATAAAGTTCTAGAAAAAATAAAACCA
>k99_79
GATGTACTGGTACTCGTTGTAGGTCGTCGTCTTGCTACCTCTGCTGCTGTCGTTCGTGGCCTCGTTGCGGTGGTCGTAGTTGTTGTGGTCGCTCTCGCAGGCCCGCCGCTCAGAGCTTGGAACGAGTTCTTGGAGACGAAGTCTCCCAGCGTTGCGCCGCGAGGCGTCGGGCGAGGTCGAGCTGCGACCTTCGCCTGGACAAAGCCGTCCTGGACCAGAGAGATGTCCATCCGCTGCGGCGGCCCCTCTTCGACGCTCCTGACGGCGCCTGTCGTTGGCCTCTGCGGGCAGGCTCGGGAGGAGTGACCGGTCTTTTTGCAGATCCAGCACTTCCGGAGCTCCCGTGCGACCTCAGGCAGGGGGCACTTGATGGCGGCGTGCGACTCGCC
>k99_83
CCCGAACACAATCGCTTTAGTCGAGCGGGAAACGCGGTGGGATTATGCGGACCCAGCCTTTACGAACGGGATCGCGGAAGACTTCTCCATCGACCAGTCTACTCACTCGCTCTTCGGCGCCTCGAAGGTTGCCGCCGACGTTTTGGTGCAGGAATACGGCCGCTATTTTGGAATGCCTACTTGCGTGCTGCGCGGCGGCTGCCTCACCGGCCCGAATCACAGCGGCGTCCAG
>k99_90
GGCTGACGTACAAGATGCGCCGTCCGTGGTCACGCGGCACGCTGGGCGTGGTGTTCAACGCGTTGTATGCCGTCATGTTCCTGTTCACGATCACGGTGATCGCGTCGATTCTCCACTCGTTCGAGTTCAACGGGCTATCCATCTTCTTCTTCCTGTTCTTCCTGTCGCTCGTGACCTTCTTCGGCCTGAAGATTCGCAATACGCGCCGCGAGCTGATGGTGGTAGAGGCGCGCGTCGGCATCGTCGGCACGATCGCGGACATCCTGTTTCTCCCCATGATACGCGCCGGCCGCTGGGTCGCGCTCCGGGCGCCGCGGGCCATCGCCACGCGGCCGGTCCGGACCATTTCCATGATCCCGTACGGCCGAAGCACCTCGAGCAGACCGTCAATCTTGTCTTCCGTACCGGTGATCTCGATGATCAGCGAATCCACCGCCACGTCGATCACCCGCGCGCGGAACACCTCGGCGAGCTGCATGACGTGCGGCCTGGATTCCGCCGACGCGGCAAC
>k99_100
AAAATACAGGTCTTTCAATGATGAAAGAAATGGATGATGCAAAAAATCTCGTTGGAATTGATTATACGAAGCATTTTGCTGATTTGGTAGAGAAAGCAGATCCTTTTGGTTCTAAAGCAGCGTTTATGCCAATGAAAGTAATTACTGCTTTGGCTTTGTTTGGTGAAAACGGCTCAACGAAAGCATTGGAAAGCTCATTAAAAAGAGGTGGAAGTGAAGAAAATTTAAACGATCTTTATTTAAACAGAGTAGGTGAGTACAAATGGAATGGTAAAACCTGGATTAAAAATAAAGAAGTTAAAGATAAAATTATTTTACGCTTTCCATCTTCTAATGCTAAAACTGTAAATAACGCTTCTTATGAAATTTCATTTGTGAACTATGCTGGAGCAGGTTTGCCTGATGA
>k99_104
GGTTCCATACATGTAACGCCAGGAATAGTGGACAACATTTGGTGCATCAGTGCGCCACGACGAGCAAATGCCTCACGCATCATGTGCACCGCTGATAAATCACCACTGACTGCAGCAAGTGCTGCAACCTGTGACACGTTGGCAACGTTTGACGTGGCATGCGATTGGAAGTTTGTTGAAGCCTTCATGATGTCTTTCGGTCCA
>k99_108
CCGCAGCATCTGACCGAGATCGAAGGGGCGGCCGTAGGGGCGCCGGCTGCTGTGCTGGCGCGCTGGACGGCGGCGGGCATGGCGCCGGCAGTCGTCATCGGCGACGGCGCGTTGGCCTTCGAGTCCCTCCTCGCCGGAGAGGCCCGCGTGTGTGGCGCGCAGCCGCTCGCCGGGACAATCGGACGAATCGCGGCGATCCGCGCGGATCGGGGAGAAGCGGTGGAGCCACACGCCGTGCGCGCGCTGTACGTCCGGCGTTCTGACGCGGAGGTCGAGAGGGACCGTGCCCGCTGATTCGAATGGTGCGGCGCCCCTCGCGCTGACGGTCGATCTCTTGTCGTCACTCGACGAACTGGACGAGGTGATGGCGGTCGA
>k99_112
ATGTCGAGCGCCAGCATTAGCGGGCGGGCGGACAAGGATGTTGATGCGCGCTCAATCGCTTTGGTGAAAACCGGTGACGAAGAAGCCAGCGCTGGCCGCGTCGATAGCGCAATTGGCTGGTATGAAACTGCGCTCGCGGTCGACCCGCGCAACCGTGCCGCTTATGTCGCCATGGCGCGCGCCGTAAAATCCCAGGGGTTG
>k99_115
GCAGTGGATGCCATACCAGAAAAAGTCGGGATGGTGCGGCTCGAATTCGGCGGGCCCGATGGAGTAGACGGAGGTGATGTCACCGATCTTGGCGAACTTTGAGGCGAAGGTTTCAGGTGGATACCTAAGGGACGAAGAACTGAAGAGTGGGATTTTGTGTTCGCGGGCGAGGCGGACGATTTCGACGGCGTCTGTAAGAGAGCCGGCGAGGGGCTTGTCGATGAAGACGGGTTTTTTCGCGGCGAGGGTCTGGCGGAATTGTTCGAGGTGGGGGCGGCCGTCGACGCTTTCGATCAGA
>k99_117
CGTCTCTGAGCTTTTCAGCTTCCATCAACTTGGCTTTTCCTATGGCCGCACTGTCGGAAACAATCGCAATCGGCCCTAACCTGGCTCCCAAGCAAGCCATGTGCATCGCCACGTGCTCAGCGGCCCCGGACGAGATTCGATATCCCACCGGAATGGCGACCGCCATGGATCTGACACAAACCTTCCCGTCCTTTCGCCATACCGTCCGTCGCTTCGTACGTCGTCTGGTGTGGCGTCGCTGTCCTCCGTGGTGCTGTAGACGTTCTCGATGGGGTCGTCGCCCTGGAAGTACTGGAGGTGGCTGTAGTCGCGCGGGAC
>k99_121
ATGAGTACAACAGTCAGTCATAACTGCGTAAGGGGCACCTGTAAATCTAGCCAATGCATGTTCAAATTCTAGTATTTTCTCAAACATTTTCGCTCAAGTGATCTTGTTTAATTTCTCGCACTGGGCAATTTAGTAATTCTGCTATAGTATTTTTAACTGCTATTCTTTTATTATTCCAATTTCTTATTAGTATAGCACGTCGTCCAATTTCTTCCAAACTTAATTCTTCTTCGCAACCACTTTTTAATTCAGCTTCTAATGTCCAGATAGTATCATGTATTCTTTTGAGCTCATCAAAACACGTTTTAACAAGAGATAAATCGAATTGTGAAGTTTGATCTTGATACCAATTAAGTTCCTCTTGATTGCTGTGTGTCCGATCCCACTTAACTTCGGCTATGGCTAATCTATCAAATAGTTCAATTACTGGAAAGTGGTAACTCATAGATATAGTCCTTCAATTTTTTCTGGA
>k99_135
AAAAGACTGTTGGCTTCTCCCAAAAAATTTACTTAAAAAATAATATTCAGACAACAATTCTTGAAAGTGCTATGCTTTGAAAGTTGTGTTTTTTTTAATTATGGCCAAAGAAAAAACAATACACACAAAAAAAGTTTGAAACATGGCCGATTTTCGTTTTAACGTGAAAGCTGATACCACAGATTAGATATAGAATAGATAGAGGCTTCCTAAATATCAGTAGTTCCCGGTCAAAGGGGCAGGATCAAGAGGGTTGCGGGGTTTCCTCTCTTCACATTGTACATTGTACACCTTGGTTGTAATAATAGAATATGTAACACCTTGT
```

Comment: Adding (made-up, but structurally correct) sample data would make this so much easier.

Comment: Got it! Added a 2block with 1st line header example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

for splitting the file into 2 line blocks the tool to use is `split`

```
split -l 2 -d file file_
```

the original `file` will generate `file_xx` sections each 2 lines long.  This will do all at once.  You can change `2` to your desired line count.

Comment: Brilliant! Thank you!

Comment: Wait, what if I want each split file to have for example 1000 of those 2line blocks? I can change the `2` to `1000`. In that case, each file would have 500 chunks. Will the last file contain the remaining number of chunks, which would not necessarily be 500, depending on the original file size? Just want to make sure there won't be any cut/dropped lines.

Comment: yes, the last split file may be short of lines if your initial file size is not a multiple of the line count you provide.  There won't be skipped/missed lines though.